# Trying to play songs from a playlist

Tags: swift

I have a media play in my app and I am allowing users to select a playlist from their device.

The playlist selection is working fine and I am storing the playlist name in a DB. Now I can't figure out how to only play songs from the selected playlist.

The code I have is:

```
let myMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
let predicateFilter = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: "Rock", forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyGenre)
myMediaQuery.filterPredicates = NSSet(object: predicateFilter) as? Set<MPMediaPredicate>
self.myMusicPlayer.setQueueWithQuery(myMediaQuery)
```

I thought just changing the filter predicates to something like MPMediaItemPropertyPlaylist would work but there is no such filter type.

How do I apply a filter to play a playlist by using the playlist name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer if anyone else is looking.

```
let myMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
let predicateFilter = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: "\(playlist)", forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName)
myMediaQuery.filterPredicates = NSSet(object: predicateFilter) as? Set<MPMediaPredicate>
myMusicPlayer.setQueueWithQuery(myMediaQuery)
```